# not to create revision for particular column change

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a model that is audited and there is a column in it that I have to update periodically. Bu I don't want to create revision for every change of this column.

Is there any configuration for not to create revision even if the property X's been changed?

Comment: Of course you can, when you specify fields, Envers just audits changes to properties which are marked with `@Audited`.

Comment: I don't want to exclude the column from audition. I only want to ignore and not create revision when that  column has been changed.
Are you sure that your method can solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only out-of-the-box way to do what you ask is to implement *Conditional Auditing*.

The conditional auditing approach described in the documentation requires that users provide their own event listeners and add your various if-checks to manipulate whether to audit rows or not.

I have documented a new concept using class-level annotations to control conditional auditing [HHH-11326](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11326) in this new JIRA.

The idea is simple, that rather than have the user muck with event listener registrations, each entity could be annotated with a new annotation that points to a  class which can serve as a means to verify whether that event listener should perform its job or not by simply returning true/false.

In your specific case, your listener might look something like this:

```
public class MyEntityListener implements AuditEventListener {
  public boolean doPostInsert(Object[] state) {
    // we always insert the new row regardless.
    return true;
  }

  public boolean doPostUpdate(Object[] oldState, Object[] newState) {
    // checks state changes and if only toggle-changed, return false.
    return !isToggleOnlyChange( oldState, newState );
  }

  public boolean doPreRemove(Object[] oldState) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The idea is that during the *update*, if only the toggle field changed, returning false would influence the listener to skip the audit.

Comment: Is there any way to get this behavior in the 5.x release of hibernate?  Aside from the Integration thing (which seems to be a global-level listener, wheras this lets you apply the audit event listener on a class-by-class basis.