# How to add field which is not audited by Envers to audit table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I am looking for a solution on how to include a field to an audit table, which is not marked as @Audited.

I have such a DB structure:

```
create table user (
    id CHAR(36) not null,
    first_name varchar(200) not null,
    last_name varchar(200) not null,
    phone_number varchar(15),
    primary key (id)
);
```

@Audited annotation is placed at first_name and last_name field in User.class, as a result below audit table is created:

```
create table user_aud (
    id CHAR(36) not null,
    rev integer not null,
    revtype tinyint,
    first_name varchar(200),
    last_name varchar(200),
    primary key (id,rev)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

I would like to additionally have in my user_aud table column phone_number but phone_number change shouldn't create a new revision. I don't want to follow changes of phone_number, but still, keep it as a part of the audit record.

I would be grateful for information how it could be done if it is possible. I am using 5.4.4.Final Hibernate version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this topic and let me know if it covers your case. For me it seems like it should work for you.

[not to create revision for particular column change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948003/not-to-create-revision-for-particular-column-change)

Comment: It seems that there is no simpler solution than writing custom auditing listeners. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yeap, I believe there is no other way